# Change joomla date format to "created from 2 hours"

Tags: date-format, joomla3.0, timeago

i tried to change my joomla 3.2 article created date to shown as "created from since"
EX: created from 2 hours ago, created from 2 weeks ago.
can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with language override and php date format

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11728790/6096

```
$post_date = '13436714242'; // strtotime();
$now = time();

// will echo "2 hours ago" (at the time of this post)
echo timespan($post_date, $now) . ' ago';
```

So for joomla dates edit the template overrides you need

```
echo timespan( strtotime($this->item->publish_up, $now) ) . ' ago';
echo timespan( strtotime($this->item->modified, $now) ) . ' ago';
echo timespan( strtotime($this->item->created, $now) ) . ' ago';
```

As you first need to turn the date back into a timestamp. I dont think there will be just one place to do it so you will have to look for several.