# get_timeago always showing 6 hours ago for current time

Tags: codeigniter, datetime

I have used `getTimeago` method in my CI model to display time in minutes ago, hours ago and days ago. For example -

In the model:

```
$rss[$i]->createdTime = get_timeago(strtotime($rss[$i]->creation_time));
```

And in the view:

```
<h5>{{cd.createdTime}}</h5>
```

However, the result is always 6 hours earlier than I expect. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728438/display-time-ago-instead-of-datetime-in-php-codeigniter

Comment: what is the value of `$rss[$i]->creation_time`

Comment: What does the `getTimeago` (`get_timeago`?) code look like? Without this it's difficult to help (although it's almost certainly timezone related - how far are you from UTC?)